# Proving heaviest edge in mst is not heavier than heaviest edge of any possible spanning tree?

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree

How to prove that the heaviest edge in mst is not heavier than heaviest edge of any possible spanning tree? by heaviest edge of any Spanning tree i mean considering any possible Spanning tree, we have to prove that the heaviest edge in mst is not heavier than heaviest edge of that spanning tree.

Comment: When [your question is closed](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/163085/755), please don't re-post it.  Instead, revise it based on the feedback you have received.  Once you have edited it, it can be considered for re-opening.  Also, I don't see that you have responded to the prior feedback, asking what you have tried.

Comment: We are not particularly looking for that contain the text of an exercise-style task along with a "I don't even know how to start".  Our goal is to build up an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e^*$ be the heaviest edge in an MST $T$, and let $A$ and $B$ be the vertices of the two connected components of $T - e^*$.

Now, by the cut property, $e^*$ is a cheapest edge with one endpoint in $A$ and one endpoint in $B$.

Since any spanning tree $T'$ must have an edge $e$ with one endpoint in $A$ and one in $B$, this means that $T'$ has an edge of cost *at least* the cost of $e^*$.